# How to change each keys in a dictionary

Tags: dictionary

Is there any way I can change the keys in a dictionary at once?

For example, `mydict={0:0.0, 1:1.1, 2:2.2}`.

How can I get `newdict={1:0.0, 2:1.1, 0:2.2}`?

Comment: Which language is this? Usually you need to create a new dictionary or new entries (depending on the amount of elements to change), because keys are that: keys.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in Python 3 so you can control the order of keys in `mydict`, then you could use a pandas `Series` to help assign new keys to the dictionary values.

```
import pandas as pd

mydict={0:0.0, 1:1.1, 2:2.2}

new_keys = [1, 2, 0]

# Make dictionary with same values assigned to new keys.
newdict = pd.Series(list(mydict.values()),
                    index=new_keys) \
                .to_dict()
newdict
# {1: 0.0, 2: 1.1, 0: 2.2}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Happy to help.  Others might find this answer more easily if you edit your question and add a "python" tag to it.  Just a thought.